# YouTrack: Configure predefined Bug Issue

Tags: youtrack

The issue type 'bug' has no estimation field as default, but I want to have an estimation for this. Is the issue type 'bug' defined in the workflows section, or is it not possible to configure predefined attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the Estimation field to a project proceed to the Custom Fields settings of the project in question. More information is here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/incloud/Manage-Custom-Fields-Per-Project.html